# Periodic Work manager fail to run in Android 8, 9 and 10

Tags: android, android-workmanager, android-10.0, android-9.0-pie

I am running a periodic work manager it is not able to work in android 8, 9 & 10. But it works fine in older versions.

Work Manager tested in Nokia 6 And One plus 7T and Moto g5 plus.

Work Manager Version used

> ```
> implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.2.0"
> ```

> ```
> compileSdkVersion 29
> buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
>
> defaultConfig {
>     applicationId "com.example.myApp"
>     minSdkVersion 21
>     targetSdkVersion 29
> ```

Proguard Rules

> -keep class * extends androidx.work.Worker
> -keep class * extends androidx.work.InputMerger
>
> -keep public class * extends androidx.work.ListenableWorker {
> public (...); }
>
> -keep class androidx.work.WorkerParameters

I also have tried a newer version but that also not work properly.

```
 public void setWorker() {
        Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build();
        PeriodicWorkRequest myWork = new PeriodicWorkRequest.
                        Builder(MyWorker.class,
                        15, TimeUnit.MINUTES, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                        .addTag("app_periodic")
                        .setConstraints(constraints).build();
    
        try {
            WorkManager.getInstance(MyApplication.this)
                    .enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("app_worker_notify", 
                     ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, myWork);

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any solution?I'm facing the same issue

Comment: One solution worked for me but not 100%. You can rebuild the entire project in Android studio 3.6.3. There is some issue with New Studio 4.0.

Comment: Please share code

Comment: its the same code . You only run in Android Studio 3.6.3. I have detailed this on another post. [Work manager do not run when proguarding app in api 27,28,29](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62807240/work-manager-do-not-run-when-proguarding-app-in-api-27-28-29)